# Jquery fadein/fadeout list

Tags: jquery

I have a list:

```
<ul class="list">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
```

I need to fadein/fadeout all this `<li>` items.  I need a loop, so when the last one appears and disappears, the first appears next.

Comment: Do you want them to fade through each other in a slide-show like manner? Or do you just want them to be highlighted in turn?

Comment: can you add more details please ? When element need to fade ? etc ...

Comment: I think he means he wants it to flash 1 then 2 then 3 then 1.... etc (fadein/fadeout each in turn then repeat).

Answer (score 2):

here is a super basic example :

```
$("#list li").hide();
var counter = $("#list li").length;

var i = setInterval(function() {
    $("#list li").eq(counter - 1).show();
    $("#list li:visible").fadeOut(2000);
    counter--;
    if (counter === 0) {
        counter = 5;
    }
}, 2000);
```

[***Click Here***](http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/t4AVw/)

Comment: great +1! I was writing the same

Answer (score 2):

An [Alternate Alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/SKSRY/2/) to what Alexander and Michael are using

Comment: I think, here is a little problem. Try to insert any html content after list. And you'll see that this additional html content ( text for example) goes down, each time list item disappears. Maybe there is need to set display:none for all syblings of fading element?

Comment: @Ahmed wow... that is a weird bug, but good catch.  it did need to set display:none (I used jquery's hide() method).  http://jsfiddle.net/SKSRY/2/

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without display none, as that makes the content inaccessible to screenreaders.

Comment: @Christopher, unfortunately display none is pretty baked into jquery.  you could use visibility:hidden with altering the opacity instead.  if you still need the elements collapsed, you could use position:absolute (not sure if that hinders screen readers).

Comment: Position absolute is fine for screenreaders as far as I've been able to discern. I think I have it working here (http://jsfiddle.net/yCcQ5/) but I can't figure out how to change it so that it transitions quickly and then has a delay (so you actually have time to read the content at full opacity).

Comment: Got it (I was adding the delay in the wrong place). http://jsfiddle.net/2DvDy/ Thanks.

Comment: Premature. It still adds the display:none, though oddly it now  changes the opacity and content of the first list item and doesn't seem to actually cycle between them. This keeps getting weirder.

Answer (score 0):

An [alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/HCFkx/1/) to the method Alexander is using.

```
function hideItem(i) {
   var items = $('.list li');
   if (i >= items.length) { return; }
   items.eq(i).fadeOut(1000, function() { showItem(i+1); }); 
}

function showItem(i) {
    var items = $('.list li');
    if (i >= items.length) { return; }
    items.eq(i).fadeIn(1000, function() { hideItem(i); });
};

showItem(0);
```

Comment: But Michael. All the other codes have the loop. And the OP asked for a nice loop here. Nevermind

Comment: OP is free to use a loop if he wants. Just showing an example where it's not necessary.